# How to allow Flutter "nested" state management?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-state

In short, I have three levels of ChangeNotifiers, the top level, intermediary level and bottom level. Naturally, bottom level is dependent on intermediary level and the latter dependent on the top level.

**My questions are:**

1. Is it possible to achieve this using the Flutter Provider plugin?
2. If Yes, when using the Provider plugin, is it possible to achieve this using only ChangeNotifierProvider only?

**More detailed scenario**

In my Flutter application, the state is logically structured in several levels. At the top, I have the `Configuration` state that stores all the configurations of the app. Then, I have a `DirectionState` and a `LocationState`, both of which are dependent on the `Configuration` state and should be notified of changes.

Then, I have my views (UIs), that is basically structured into a Stateful widget class for encoding the logic of the UI only, and a UI model class for implementing the business logic of the UI, somewhat the state of one UI only. The latter class implements the `ChangeNotifier` so that the UI updates everytime its model changes. That part is pretty simple.

It becomes complex when each model's UI is dependent both on the `DirectionState` and a `LocationState` that is then dependent on the `Configuration` state. All UI's model should be able to change the `Configuration` state that should then have all effect on the entire tree. Similarly, a change in both the `Direction` state and `Location` state should affect all UI's model and ultimately the UI themselves.

Comment: Have you already managed to update a provider from another one, for example if Configuration has a change that needs to be reflected in DirectonState, can you update it? Or is it what you are asking about?

Comment: RiverPod makes this pretty easy.  Any provider can depend on upstream providers rather trivially (using ref.watch in their create function).

Answer (score 1):

With the `Provider` package a `Provider` widget will provide to all of it's children an object (we can call it a state).

With `context.read<MyType>()` you can retrieve the value of one of your providers.

Also calling `context.watch<MyType>()` inside a build method will rebuild your widget when the provider changes.

In your case we can image this structure:

```
Provider(
  create: (_) => Configuration(),
  child: Provider(
    create: (_) => DirectionState(),
    child: Provider(
      create: (_) => LocationState(),
      child: ...
    )
  )
)
```

Also you should check the [Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) library witch make the state management easier than the `Provider` library. (Bloc is based on the `Provider` package)